# Spring webflux security - Form based auth testing using postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am using Spring boot for backend and reactjs for front and both are running as different application with context switching on the load balancer so as to have the same app URL for both.

**Context Switching:-**

> 1. All requests routed to reach JS by default
> 2. Request starts with /api/v1/* will be routed to Spring boot backend.

Using Spring webflux security for the Spring boot application.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);

    return http.authorizeExchange()
        .matchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
        .permitAll()
        .pathMatchers(props.getSecurity().getIgnorePatterns())
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
        .accessDeniedHandler((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
        .and()
        .build();
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(
                userDetailsService);
    authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationManager;
}

@Bean
public ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository();
    securityContextRepository.setSpringSecurityContextAttrName("app-security-context");
    return securityContextRepository;
}
```

Using form based authentication here. All API's are restricted by default.

Need to test the login and API's with proper authentication. My react app is not yet ready so trying to use Postman for testing.

How to test the form login with postman?

Also, How to pass the login session for testing the other authenticated API's?

Comment: `Any help on testing login and other API's with Postman` you need to be more concrete in your question, too vague question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Updated my question

Comment: `How to test the form login with postman?` still too vague. The answer is, you make requests with postman. Post what you have tried, what errors you get, etc. If you dont know how to start you google around, stack overflow is for specific detailed coding issues please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users